# Less lighten function, non-linear results?

Tags: css, colors, less

using less darkem/lighten to take a base colour and add 10 shades of darkness/lightness to it.

**less code**

```
@baseColour:            #B61840;
@baseColour_d9:         darken(@baseColour,90%);
@baseColour_d8:         darken(@baseColour,80%);
@baseColour_d7:         darken(@baseColour,70%);
@baseColour_d6:         darken(@baseColour,60%);
@baseColour_d5:         darken(@baseColour,50%);
@baseColour_d4:         darken(@baseColour,40%);
@baseColour_d3:         darken(@baseColour,30%);
@baseColour_d2:         darken(@baseColour,20%);
@baseColour_d1:         darken(@baseColour,10%);
@baseColour_l1:         lighten(@baseColour,10%);
@baseColour_l2:         lighten(@baseColour,20%);
@baseColour_l3:         lighten(@baseColour,30%);
@baseColour_l4:         lighten(@baseColour,40%);
@baseColour_l5:         lighten(@baseColour,50%);
@baseColour_l6:         lighten(@baseColour,60%);
@baseColour_l7:         lighten(@baseColour,70%);
@baseColour_l8:         lighten(@baseColour,80%);
@baseColour_l9:         lighten(@baseColour,90%);
@baseColour_l95:        lighten(@baseColour,95%);
@baseColour_l975:       lighten(@baseColour,97.5%);
.baseColour_d9{background-color:@baseColour_d9; width:132px;height:32px;}
.baseColour_d8{background-color:@baseColour_d8; width:132px;height:32px;}
.baseColour_d7{background-color:@baseColour_d7; width:132px;height:32px;}
.baseColour_d6{background-color:@baseColour_d6; width:132px;height:32px;}
.baseColour_d5{background-color:@baseColour_d5; width:132px;height:32px;}
.baseColour_d4{background-color:@baseColour_d4; width:132px;height:32px;}
.baseColour_d3{background-color:@baseColour_d3; width:132px;height:32px;}
.baseColour_d2{background-color:@baseColour_d2; width:132px;height:32px;}
.baseColour_d1{background-color:@baseColour_d1; width:132px;height:32px;}
.baseColour{background-color:@baseColour;   width:132px;height:32px;}
.baseColour_l1{background-color:@baseColour_l1; width:132px;height:32px;}
.baseColour_l2{background-color:@baseColour_l2; width:132px;height:32px;}
.baseColour_l3{background-color:@baseColour_l3; width:132px;height:32px;}
.baseColour_l4{background-color:@baseColour_l4; width:132px;height:32px;}
.baseColour_l5{background-color:@baseColour_l5; width:132px;height:32px;}
.baseColour_l6{background-color:@baseColour_l6; width:132px;height:32px;}
.baseColour_l7{background-color:@baseColour_l7; width:132px;height:32px;}
.baseColour_l8{background-color:@baseColour_l8; width:132px;height:32px;}
.baseColour_l9{background-color:@baseColour_l9; width:132px;height:32px;}
.baseColour_l95{background-color:@baseColour_l95;width:132px;height:32px;}
.baseColour_l975{background-color:@baseColour_l975;width:132px;height:32px;}
```

**HTML code:**

```
 <div class='baseColour_d9'>baseColour_d9</div>
<div class='baseColour_d8'>baseColour_d8</div>
<div class='baseColour_d7'>baseColour_d7</div>
<div class='baseColour_d6'>baseColour_d6</div>
<div class='baseColour_d5'>baseColour_d5</div>
<div class='baseColour_d4'>baseColour_d4</div>
<div class='baseColour_d3'>baseColour_d3</div>
<div class='baseColour_d2'>baseColour_d2</div>
<div class='baseColour_d1'>baseColour_d1</div>
<div class='baseColour'>baseColour</div>
<div class='baseColour_l1'>baseColour_l1</div>
<div class='baseColour_l2'>baseColour_l2</div>
<div class='baseColour_l3'>baseColour_l3</div>
<div class='baseColour_l4'>baseColour_l4</div>
<div class='baseColour_l5'>baseColour_l5</div>
<div class='baseColour_l6'>baseColour_l6</div>
<div class='baseColour_l7'>baseColour_l7</div>
<div class='baseColour_l8'>baseColour_l8</div>
<div class='baseColour_l9'>baseColour_l9</div>
<div class='baseColour_l95'>baseColour_l95</div>
<div class='baseColour_l975'>baseColour_l975</div>
```

**results:**
[image]

my question:
Why is there such a non-linear drop off between d4 & d5 as well as l5 & l6?

Answer (score 0):

I never worked out why it worked as it did but this is the effect i was looking for:

```
@baseColour:            #B61840;
@baseColour_d9:         multiply(@baseColour,#191919);
@baseColour_d8:         multiply(@baseColour,#323232);
@baseColour_d7:         multiply(@baseColour,#4B4B4B);
@baseColour_d6:         multiply(@baseColour,#646464);
@baseColour_d5:         multiply(@baseColour,#7D7D7D);
@baseColour_d4:         multiply(@baseColour,#969696);
@baseColour_d3:         multiply(@baseColour,#AFAFAF);
@baseColour_d2:         multiply(@baseColour,#C8C8C8);
@baseColour_d1:         multiply(@baseColour,#E1E1E1);
@baseColour_l1:         screen(@baseColour,#191919);
@baseColour_l2:         screen(@baseColour,#323232);
@baseColour_l3:         screen(@baseColour,#4B4B4B);
@baseColour_l4:         screen(@baseColour,#646464);
@baseColour_l5:         screen(@baseColour,#7D7D7D);
@baseColour_l6:         screen(@baseColour,#969696);
@baseColour_l7:         screen(@baseColour,#AFAFAF);
@baseColour_l8:         screen(@baseColour,#C8C8C8);
@baseColour_l9:         screen(@baseColour,#E1E1E1);
@baseColour_l95:        screen(@baseColour,#E6E6E6);
@baseColour_l975:       screen(@baseColour,#EBEBEB);
```

[image]

Comment: Just in case, you can get the same with `(@baseColour * .1)`, `(@baseColour * .2)`, `(@baseColour * .3)` etc.

Comment: Also see this [codepen](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/yozvw) for a bit more generic implementation with two different methods.